# seaborn.FacetGrid col parameter not behaving as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The following is my code.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
g = sns.FacetGrid(titanic, col="sex")
g = g.map(plt.hist, "age")
```

The Histogram looks like as shown.

[image: current histogram output]

Now I have a question about the parameter `col`. I see two histograms arranged in a row. But I have mentioned that `col=sex`. So what is the purpose of `col` parameter and why histograms are arranged in a rowwise fashion?

Comment: Do you read http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html ? FacetGrid subplots grid for plotting conditional relationships. Therefore when you select `sex` seaborn plots all histogram according to sex values. If you select another column, i.e., with three values you will get 3 histograms.

Comment: Ok, so `col` parameter just gives names of the dataframe columns. Makes sense.

Comment: *col parameter not behaving as expected* ... and what was the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the `col` parameter subsets the data frame into grouped by the variable that matches the indicated argument name. Each group will be plotted in a separate column in the resulting plot. In your case, the data frame variable `sex` has two groups: males and females. In the resulting plot, each of these groups have been plotted plotted in a separate column, that's why there are two columns and one row in your plot.

From the [`FaceGrid`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) docstring:

> row, col, hue : strings
>
> Variables that define subsets of the data, which will be drawn on separate facets in the grid. See the *_order parameters to control the order of levels of this variable.